# Android having paragraph and numbering/bullets on textview

Tags: android

I am creating an app, which have some description that have steps. For example:

How to transfer:

- -Do you have credit card
- -If you dont make a fake one
- -Then insert it to ATM
- -And watch it explode

How to catch a fish:

- Open console
- use cheat
- you got one

and getting longer...

these description(steps) will be displayed in a scrollview, right now i make it using java, setText use "\n" and "   " extra empty space to trick the diplay. However this wont work for different resolutions. How to make textview display something like this?

based on the answer,I tried this:
.xml on layout

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCBAjud"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
                android:text="@string/transfer"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                />
    </ScrollView>
```

and define the string:

```
 <string name="transfer">how to transfer \n
        <ul>
        <li>-Do you have credit card</li> 
        <li>-If you dont make a fake one</li>
         <li>-Then insert it to ATM</li> 
         <li>-And watch it explode</li>
         </ul></string>
```

but the output become:

```
How to transfer -Do you have credit card -If you dont make a fake one -Then insert it to ATM -And watch it explode
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your text is static then you can extend `TextView` to automatically prepend a `BulletSpan` before your `android:text`:

**layout.xml**

```
<BulletTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Orange" />
<BulletTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Banana" />
```

**BulletTextView.java**

```
/**
 * {@link TextView} that automatically adds bullet point to text if set in layout
 */
public class BulletTextView extends TextView {
    public BulletTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        addBullet();
    }

    public BulletTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        addBullet();
    }

    public BulletTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        addBullet();
    }

    public BulletTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        addBullet();
    }

    private void addBullet() {
        CharSequence text = getText();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            return;
        }
        SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(text);
        spannable.setSpan(new BulletSpan(16), 0, text.length(), 0);
        setText(spannable);
    }
}
```

You can further customize this by adding custom attribute for indentation.

Comment: this is an overkill, but this occur when i try :Call requires API level 21 (current min is 8): new android.widget.TextView

Comment: Remove the last constructor, it's only added since API 21. It may be more than what you need now, but it keeps your code clean of logic to set HTML text. Also imagine when you need to adjust vertical spacing between items.

Comment: It works .That would be another problem. Any idea about adjusting the textview so they dont attached to the left screen?

Comment: It's the same as `TextView`. Use layout attributes such as `android:padding`, `android:layout_margin`, etc

Comment: 1 more question, the textview is somehow auto set its own line to two,why

Comment: Maybe because the content could not fit into 1 line. If you don't want that then set `android:singleLine="true"` `android:ellipsize="end"`, or if font size can be adjusted set it smaller.

Comment: its even split one word, example: discussion will be  discuss on 1st line then ion on 2nd

Comment: if i add singeline = true it will remove the 2nd line so it ll be discuss only

Comment: it appears to be the text width which was set as wrap content, now its fill parent, the display working just fine

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Unicode as bullets**

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String circle = "\u25CF";
    String sentence = circle + "  " + "Hello its me"+ "\n";
    tv.setText(sentence);
```

Use any **symbols, bullets** etc by changing **Unicode** and
Unicode Table is here.
http://unicode-table.com/en/#box-drawing

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<br>` instead of \n and call `HTML.fromHtml` to convert it to HTML.

Like this:

```
String sHTML = " <string name=\"transfer\">how to transfer<br>" +
    "<br>" +
    "&#8226; Do you have credit card<br>" +
    "&#8226; If you dont make a fake one<br>" +
    "&#8226; Then insert it to ATM<br>" +
    "&#8226; And watch it explode<br>" +
    "</string>";

TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCBAjud);
textView1.setText(Html.fromHtml(sHTML, null, null));
```

Comment: whats the null,null ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String, android.text.Html.ImageGetter, android.text.Html.TagHandler)

Comment: how about adjusting the line(s) i mean its all attached to the left screen

Comment: I modified my answer so that you will see bullets and a small indentation.
UL/LI are not really supported by that function fromHtml.

Answer (score 1):

In the string.xml write the following code:

```
<string name="transfer">how to transfer \n<ul><li>-Do you have credit card</li>
<li>-If you dont make a fake one</li>
<li>-Then insert it to ATM</li>
<li>-And watch it explode</li>
</ul></string>

 <string name="catch"><ul><li>Open console</li>
<li>use cheat</li>
<li>you got one</li>
</ul></string>
```

And in your activity.xml

```
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/transfer"       
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_16sp" />

 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/catch"       
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_16sp" />
```

Comment: its displayed like : How to transfer -Do you have credit card -If you dont make a fake one -Then insert it to ATM -And watch it explode .Not in a list

Comment: In my case the bullets are comming..can you share your code for more clarification

Comment: hang on, what layout do i need to use? linear? relative? or? Note: i use scrollview inside a layout parent

Comment: Simply use linearlayout

Comment: i do, does orientation affect it ? i set as vertical

Comment: If you set the orientation vertical it means the next view which you add comes down after your first textview .

Comment: somehow the display still looks like in one sentence

Comment: then try adding \n in every end of the li like <li>-If you dont make a fake one \n </li>

Comment: still wont apply, is this method need some SDK requirement? level of api

Comment: This answer isn't helpful. <ul><li> Doesn't work and neither indentation.

Comment: @RohitSharma the best approch would be to use webview and use the followig code   webView.loadData(text, "text/html", "UTF-8");

Comment: Thanks @jyomin I'm using a RelativeLayout to display static 'instructions' and it has buttons on it as well which are calling another activity - but this isn't solving the issue in my case.

Answer (score 1):

**You can customize BulletSpan in your own way like this:**

```
    public class CustomBulletSpan implements LeadingMarginSpan, ParcelableSpan {
    private final int mGapWidth;
    private final boolean mWantColor;
    private final int mColor;

    private static final int BULLET_RADIUS = 3;
    private static Path sBulletPath = null;
    public static final int STANDARD_GAP_WIDTH = 2;

    public CustomBulletSpan(int gapWidth) {
        mGapWidth = gapWidth;
        mWantColor = false;
        mColor = 0;
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mGapWidth);
        dest.writeInt(mWantColor ? 1 : 0);
        dest.writeInt(mColor);
    }

    public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first) {
        return 2 * BULLET_RADIUS + mGapWidth;
    }

    public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir, int top, int baseline, int bottom,
            CharSequence text, int start, int end, boolean first, Layout l) {
        // Here I shifted the bullets to right by the given half bullet
        x += mGapWidth / 2;
        if (((Spanned) text).getSpanStart(this) == start) {
            Paint.Style style = p.getStyle();
            int oldcolor = 0;

            if (mWantColor) {
                oldcolor = p.getColor();
                p.setColor(mColor);
            }

            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            if (c.isHardwareAccelerated()) {
                if (sBulletPath == null) {
                    sBulletPath = new Path();
                    // Bullet is slightly better to avoid aliasing artifacts on
                    // mdpi devices.
                    sBulletPath.addCircle(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.2f * BULLET_RADIUS, Direction.CW);
                }

                c.save();
                c.translate(x + dir * BULLET_RADIUS, (top + bottom) / 2.0f);
                c.drawPath(sBulletPath, p);
                c.restore();
            } else {
                c.drawCircle(x + dir * BULLET_RADIUS, (top + bottom) / 2.0f, BULLET_RADIUS, p);
            }

            if (mWantColor) {
                p.setColor(oldcolor);
            }

            p.setStyle(style);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getSpanTypeId() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add in new lines  \n

```
    <li>-Do you have credit card</li> \n 
    <li>-If you dont make a fake one</li> \n
     <li>-Then insert it to ATM</li> \n 
     <li>-And watch it explode</li> \n

    </string>
```